# How to check if date format on the device is US?

Tags: android, date-format

I basically have to check if the date format on a device is US or `mm.dd` so I can turn on or off a certain widget.

I thought of using `DateFormat` (like I use it when checking if time is set to 24hrs, `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)`), but I could not find a way to make comparison of date format.

Anyone can give me a hint? Am I using the wrong class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this this way

```
final String format = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT);
if (format.contains("MM-dd")) { //US date format
    //do something
}
```

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424693/why-regional-date-format-returns-empty-string) because the format is sometimes empty string.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the TimeZone class, it might help with what you need. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html